# How to limit a block of text to the size of an image?

Tags: html, css, jinja2

I need to make blocks of the same width and height. At the same time, do not make the size fixed to adapt to the screen of the mobile device.

**Text is small**

[image]

**Text is long**

[image]

```
<style>
    .wrapper {
        display: inline-flex;
    }

    .item {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
</style>

<div>
    {% for playlist in library['playlists'] %}
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="item">
            <img src={{ pic }} alt={{ playlist['description'] }}>
            <p style="text-align: left;"><input type="checkbox" name="playlist_item" value={{ playlist['kind'] }}>{{ playlist['title'] }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

**UPDATE**:

If I add `class wrapper` to outside `div`. Blocks are the same size. But in one line with vertical scrollbar. How do it horizontal?

```
<div class="wrapper">
    {% for playlist in library['playlists'] %}
    <div class="wrapper">
    ...
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

[image]

For result, I want to something like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution i can think of is to limit the parent of the `img` to the size on the `img` then the text will flow in the space it has.

Now this is not reliable at this point because  min-content is not widely [supported](https://caniuse.com/#search=min-content)

```css
.container {
  max-width: min-content;
  border: 1px solid;
  /* just for show */
  margin-right: 5px;
  
}

.item>img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

 /* just for show */
.flex{
  display:flex;
  align-items:flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/797/100/300" />
    <p style="text-align: left;">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</p>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/785/200/300" />
    <p style="text-align: left;">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</p>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/796/300/300" />
    <p style="text-align: left;">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</p>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/795/400/300" />
    <p style="text-align: left;">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</p>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/799/500/300" />
    <p style="text-align: left;">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The widest element here is the `p`, because images take time to load so at the beginning the `img` will be 0 width and the text will force the table to expand, also i was just testing with display table and forgot it, it doesn't make any difference in this situation

Comment: @Viewed You want to put images next to each other with a horizontal scroll ?

Comment: Added screenshot for final result

Comment: @Viewed You'd probably use CSS grid for that

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the [word-break CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break).

Demo:
https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/pages/css/word-break.html

But to break the sentence, so it always fit on one line, try to use [text-overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow):

```css
.limited{
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden
}

.container{
  max-width:200px
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a5/Halton_sequence_2_3.svg/240px-Halton_sequence_2_3.svg.png">
  <div class="limited">Even though standard Halton sequences perform very well in low dimensions, correlation problems have been noted between sequences generated from higher primes.
    </div>
</div>
```